# Cannot get very simple delegatecall to work

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

I have this super simple code:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.13;

contract test1{
    
    uint256 public number;
    address public sender;
    
    function setNumber(uint256 _number) public {
        number = _number;
        sender = msg.sender;
    }
}

contract test2{

    bool public success;
    
    function sendNumber(address _contractaddress) public {
        
        (bool _success, ) = _contractaddress.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("setNumber(uint256)",69));
        success = _success;
    }
}
```

I'm deploying both contracts, then calling sendNumber of the second contract and passing the address of the first contract. I then call number() and sender() on the first contract, but both are unset.

Is there some dumb syntax error I am making here? `success` is returning true on the call.

Comment: i don't see any function call number or sender in the first contract. If you want to see the value of it i don't think u need ().

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `delegatecall` with `call` method made possible state update of contract `test`. Example:

```
contract test1{
    
    uint256 public number;
    address public sender;
    
    function setNumber(uint256 _number) public {
        number = _number;
        sender = msg.sender;
    }
}

contract test2{
    bool public success;
    
    function sendNumber(address _contractaddress) public {
        (bool _success,) = address(_contractaddress).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("setNumber(uint256)", 69));
        success = _success;
    }
}
```

When using `delegatecall` the storage still refer to the calling contract, but when using `call` like in my example the storage of the called contract is getting updated.